# Changing jquery-bootgrid page to display selected data-row-id using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootgrid

I'm using a jquery-bootgrid to display paged data.  Is there a way to use javascript to change to a given bootgrid page based on data-row-id?  Basically the user can click on a marker on a map and I need the bootgrid to change to the page with the matching data-row-id.

Comment: `$('[data-row-id="your_id"]').doSomething();//...`

Comment: It's the doSomething bit I need. How do I get the bootgrid to change the the page that contains the "your_id"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but, since it is sitting here unanswered:

```
  $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
  {
     YourTableName.find(".ClassNameForYourLink").on("click", function(event)
     {
        location.href="PageYouWanttoGoTo";
     }
  }
```